# How to access AEM Core models in a Sling model

Tags: java, aem, sling

Specifically, I am trying to enable .SVG files to be usable by the core image component.

Right now I am making a sling model that ideally I would like to access the returned values of the getSrc() and getFileReference() classes in the core AEM Component interface located [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/models/Image.java).

I am very new to AEM development and Sling models. Am I missing some vital functionality that would let me do this?

Here is my code, which probably isn't at all helpful at this point.

```
package com.site.core.models;

import com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.models.Image;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.*;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.*;

import org.apache.sling.settings.SlingSettingsService;
import javax.jcr.Node;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class)
public class ImageModel {

    private String src = Image.getSrc(); 

    return src;

}
```

Comment: The source you are referencing is an interface, you can look at the [impl here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/internal/models/v1/ImageImpl.java) you can make your own impl and use it in your own copy of the image component

Comment: Awesome, so if i'm understanding this correctly I can use the impl you linked as a base and modify it to suit my needs? If thats the case, when the Image model is being called currently what is directing it towards that impl file? is that something i will have to change in pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, the link you are referring to is an interface, the implementation of that interface is [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/internal/models/v1/ImageImpl.java)

In order to use your own implementation, you have two options:

1. In the image component html, change the `data-sly-use` to refer to your impl: `com.site.core.models.ImageModel`
2. Create a separate model that implements the `Image` interface and give it a high ranking to be picked up instead of the existing impl.

> Disclaimer: I have not tested #2 but the [documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scripting/scripting-htl.html#sling-models-use-provider) suggests that it's possible.